No response from API Qradar request
This is part of PowerShell script to retrieve events with Qradar API request, in the previous requests in the script I got response with JSON output, but in the last step request (results) I got an empty response:
$search_id = $post0.search_id
$url4 = "https:/x.x.x.x/api/ariel/searches/"+$search_id+"/results"
$post2 = Invoke-RestMethod -WebSession $session -Method GET -Headers $headers -Uri $url4
Write-Output @($post2.events)

I tried all the combination with ConvertTo-Json (from) but it didn't work
Anybody know why?
